# Skip JPA life cycle methods while running tests

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity Post and an event listener is registered with it as shown here.

```
@EntityListeners({EntityAuditor.class})
@Entity 
class Post {
  ...
}
```

Here is how my EntityAuditor listener class looks like:

```
public class EntityAuditor {
  @PostPersist
  void publishToKafka(Object object) {
      // publish new object to Kafka
  }
}
```

I don't want this to be called when my unit/integration test try to create a new post. Is there a way I can skip the JPA lifecycle hooks or the event listener only for tests?

Comment: Could you try it?

Comment: Hey, sorry..missed this. I'll try and let you know

Comment: Hey @areus, my event listeners are still running even after putting this config in test directory

Comment: Are you sure META-INF/orm.xml is on your classpath when running the tests? You could also try to create a NoOpEntityAuditor and set it on the `<entity-listeners>` element to override the entity listener, instead of an empty list

Answer (score 2):

According to the JPA spec The `EntityListeners` annotation can be overridden with the `<entity-listeners>` subelement of the `<entity>` element in the persistence object/relational
mapping file.

So, you should include a META-INF/orm.xml file, **only on your test environment**, and set an empty `<entity-listeners>` for your entity. Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_2.xsd"
                 version="2.2">
    <entity class="yourpackage.Post">
        <entity-listeners />
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```